# wordpress - current timezone using php

Tags: php, wordpress, timezone

I need to display current time and timezone in my wordpress site.

I know how to get current time. But I donot know how to get timezone.

I'm unable to use any plugin for this.

Somebody please help me to get timezone using php code

Comment: I assume you mean the client timezone? Note the difference between server and client timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
        if (date_default_timezone_get()) {

            echo 'Current Time in  ' . date_default_timezone_get() . ':';

        }
?>
```

Have a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: wow!!!.. such a simple code.. It works for me like a charm.. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This will give you the time zone of your *server* - not the person visiting your web site.

Answer (score 4):

```
/**
 * This is how wordpress gets the current date and time
 * as per the timezone setting used in the WP-Admin settings
 * @see /wp-admin/options-general.php:160
 */
$now = date_create( date_i18n( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) );
```

Comment: how would one get timezone for each user. What I mean if you get a timezone from settings, according to my understanding it will be the same for all, but what if I want to detect the time zone of different users

Comment: if you're using php to detect the timezone, it'll give you the timezone of your server. if you're looking to grab the timezone of your user's, you'd need to use javascript since it runs on their machines, so it uses their timezone

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the time zone like I have set the time zone to India

```
      <?php 
         if(empty($_GET['useroffset'])){ 
            echo '<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript"> 
                  var curDateTime = new Date() 
                  document.write("GMT Offset for your time zone is ") 
                  document.write(-(curDateTime.getTimezoneOffset()/60)) 
                 </SCRIPT>'; 
         } 
         elseif(is_numeric($_GET['useroffset'])){ 
            $useroffset = $_GET['useroffset']; 
            echo $useroffset; 
         } 
     ?>
```

New EDIT on requirement

You need the time on the client which you can get from Javascript using:

```
d=new Date();
offset=d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

Which returns the users offset from GMT in minutes. Pass this to your PHP (AJAX) and use something like:

```
  $zero = 0;
  $timenow = date("D d M Y H:i:s");
  $tserver = strtotime($timenow, $zero);
  $timenow .= " UTC";
  $tUTC = strtotime($timenow, $zero);
  $diff = ($tserver - $tUTC)/60;
//  echo("Client Difference:" . $offset . " Server Difference:" . $diff);
  $offset =  $diff - $offset;
```

This gives you the offset between the server and the client which you can then apply to your calculations.

Comment: @Deonia: sorry. It displays the timezone which have set. I need to display default timezone.

Comment: Are you looking for displaying the timezone depending on visitors time zone?

Comment: @Veena Please see the new edit. You can get the offset by this and can refine further

Comment: The *current* offset cannot be applied to *all* dates on the back end, because offsets can change for DST and other anomalies. See "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).